# oracle sql join SUM result doubled on some rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, inner-join

I have the following two SQL statements which are returning double the sum on some rows and would appreciate some help sorting.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT A.ITMCOD
    ,I.ITMDSC
    ,A.CTLGRP
    ,SUM(A.CASQTY) thesum
    ,(C.FIFODT + I.STPSHP) STOP_SHIP_DATE
FROM INVENT_VIEW A
INNER JOIN ITMMST I ON A.ITMCOD = I.ITMCOD
INNER JOIN CTLGRP C ON A.CTLGRP = C.CTLGRP
WHERE A.ITMCOD LIKE 'PS%687%'
GROUP BY A.ITMCOD
    ,I.ITMDSC
    ,A.CTLGRP
    ,C.FIFODT
    ,I.STPSHP
)
ORDER BY ITMCOD
```

My second trial, where i thought the joins were the issue, and which returns identical results is as follows:

```
SELECT INVENT_VIEW.ITMCOD
  ,ITMMST.ITMDSC
  ,CTLGRP.CTLGRP
  ,SUM(INVENT_VIEW.CASQTY) thesum
  ,(CTLGRP.FIFODT + ITMMST.STPSHP) STOP_SHIP_DATE
FROM INVENT_VIEW
  ,CTLGRP
  ,ITMMST
WHERE ITMMST.ITMCOD = INVENT_VIEW.ITMCOD
  AND (CTLGRP.CTLGRP = INVENT_VIEW.CTLGRP)
  AND (INVENT_VIEW.ITMCOD LIKE 'PS%687%')
GROUP BY INVENT_VIEW.ITMCOD
  ,ITMMST.ITMDSC
  ,CTLGRP.CTLGRP
  ,CTLGRP.FIFODT
  ,ITMMST.STPSHP
```

**RESULT**

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║  "ITMCOD"  ║    "ITMDSC"    ║   "CTLGRP"   ║ "THESUM" ║ "STOP_SHIP_DATE" ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ "PS00687A" ║ "gROOVY BRUSH" ║ "4066ZDPOO4" ║    93600 ║ 26-DEC-16        ║
║ "PS00687A" ║ "gROOVY BRUSH" ║ "5385POSOO4" ║     3600 ║ 08-MAY-18        ║
║ "PS00687A" ║ "gROOVY BRUSH" ║ "5299POS001" ║     9922 ║ 08-MAY-18        ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

The error is in the first row, where the sum should be half of what is shown (46800). The other two results are correct.

I have tried putting DISTINCT right after sum, but this just returns the first value for the first row which is 3600. i have also placed distinct right after the SELECT statement but this makes no difference.

Would really appreciate help on this.

thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to mef who was right about duplicates in the joined tables, i was able to  get my desired results! I also edited the SQL to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.ITMCOD
    ,I.ITMDSC
    ,A.CTLGRP
    ,SUM(A.CASQTY) QTY
    ,CASE 
        WHEN C.STPDAT IS NOT NULL
            THEN C.STPDAT
        ELSE (C.FIFODT + I.STPSHP)
        END AS STOP_SHIP_DATE
FROM INVENT_VIEW A
INNER JOIN ITMMST I ON A.ITMCOD = I.ITMCOD
INNER JOIN CTLGRP C ON (
        (A.CTLGRP = C.CTLGRP)
        AND (A.ITMCOD = C.ITMCOD)   <- added
        )
WHERE A.ITMCOD LIKE 'PS%'
    AND C.QASTAT = 'RL'      <- added
GROUP BY A.ITMCOD
    ,I.ITMDSC
    ,A.CTLGRP
    ,C.FIFODT
    ,I.STPSHP
    ,C.STPDAT
)
ORDER BY ITMCOD
```

Comment: Give us your data struncture and input, its hard to see the problem like this. I think you may have duplicate rows and thats why you are getting X2

Comment: You would need to provide the sample data for all the tables involved that goes along with the output you provided. Have you tried running the query without the sum/group by? That way, you ought to be able to see where the rows are being duplicated; my guess is that at least one of your joins is 1-to-many, rather than 1-to-1, meaning your output may end up with more rows than you are perhaps expecting.

Comment: you have a duplicate row(used data wise) is any of your table. that's why its making the sum double .

Comment: Thanks for your responses, i indeed had duplicates ! I have updated the question to show the final query. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a duplicate for your first record inside `INVENT_VIEW` or `CTLGRP`.

Check with these two queries, each of them should return one in case the data is correct:

```
-- check whether there is a duplicate inside INVENT_VIEW
select count(1) from INVENT_VIEW where CTLGRP = '4066ZDPOO4' and ITMCOD = 'PS00687A'

-- check whether there is a duplicate inside CTLGRP
select count(1) from CTLGRP where CTLGRP = '4066ZDPOO4'
```

In case one of these queries returns a value above than one, then there is a duplicate in your source data. (You may want to double-check the view's query).

Otherwise, if both the queries return one, there's a problem with your join. In such case please share the structure of your tables.

Comment: @ downvoter > please explain what the problem is in the answer I wrote. I think I gave OP the right directions in order to solve this type of issues, and he'll be able to apply it to this and other similar problems he'll meet in the future.

Comment: Hi, No idea why this was downvoted but this was actually the reason why i was getting those results ! So thank you mef ! I edited the SQL to further isolate the results returned by including ITMCOD and QASTAT columns in the inner join clause. Ill edit the answer to show this. Cheers mate